# Nginx's Too many open files, is setting of worker_rlimit_nofile enough?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ulimit, max-file-descriptors

Is setting the right value of `worker_rlimit_nofile` in nginx.conf enough solve the issue of `Too many open files` in nginx?

Or do I still need to update the `sysctl.conf` and `limits.conf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux, you can see if that option has changed the limits of the process by running:

```
cat /proc/<PID>/limits
```

Where `<PID>` is the process ID of nginex. Test on a development environment.

If that option is not changing the limits or if you have a too restrictive hard limit you need to change the `nofile` in the /etc/security/limits.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to modify limits.conf.  The point of worker_rlimit_nofile is to provide a quick and dirty way to do this via RLIMIT_NOFILE.

However, there are hard system limits set by the OS which you may need to override using sysctl.conf.

In practice, I usually set my fs.file-max in sysctl to about 4X the rlimit for my apps. No basis for this other than I never want something to fail due to hitting this limit.  And a 2-4X range is usually sufficiently high to only trigger when there's a major issue with the apps.